# How to make a alarm open a new activity android studio kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, alarm, ringtone

So what I have seen in tutorials of alarms in kotlin android studio, I just find alarms that make a notification apeear, but the idea for this app is that you need to turn off the alarm with math problems, so I need a new activity, the only problem is that I dont know how to do it.

I folowed this instructions:
https://youtu.be/n9FN0odXqi0

Note: The instructions from above do open a new activity but you need to click the notification and there is no ring tone, if some one can help with that too I would be very gratefull :))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60767216/506796